# Geometrically speaking: what distinguishes a subspace vs a non-subspace in finite dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry, definition, intuition

Suppose we have $\mathbb{R}$

Then imagine an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, let's call it $I$.

Then $I$ is not a subspace, since addition of two elements do not necessarily lie in the set.

It seems to me that the only subspace in $\mathbb{R}$ is the set $\{0\}$.

Likewise, if we take some arbitrary chunk from $\mathbb{R}^n$, it might not be a subspace. But others might, e.g., a hyperplane.

So, geometrically speaking, how do we generate set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are subspaces?

Do we always visualize it as some line, plane, passing through the origin, but not other objects such as a sphere, or a ball? Why is this true?

Comment: Yes, subspace is the common generalization to higher dimensions of 'lines and planes through the origin' of the 3d space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and $V\neq\{0\}$, then there is some $v\in V$ such that $v\neq0$. But then the line $\{\lambda v\mid\lambda\in\mathbb R\}$ is a subset of $V$. So, no ball is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and the same argument applies to spheres. Actually, the same argument applies to any bounded subset $\mathbb R^n$ other than $\{0\}$.

Comment: So is there some purely topological way of describing a subspace of $R^n$, without using $\{v\in X| \lambda v \in X, v_1 + v_2 \in X\}$, e.g., a set being open, unbounded, etc. etc. is necessary and sufficient to be a subspace

Comment: No, because every subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ which is not a subspace. However, no open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ other than $\mathbb R^n$ itself is a subspace. And every subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is closed.